# could not send newsletter using drupal 7 simple news module

Tags: drupal-7

I have installed Drupal 7 simple-news module and its dependency modules. 
I have finished all the steps as in [Reference](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2012/04/03/drupal-7-create-newsletter-by-simplenews-1/)

But at point # 11, i couldn't find two radio buttons, instead i have found only one disabled check box with text like " This newsletter is pending "

[image]

what i'm missing here ?

Comment: Now i can able to send it. But i have received mail in only plain text not in HTML format . Please check this link http://drupal.org/node/1048254#comment-6642942

Answer (score 4):

Test ones go immediately but when you want to send for subscribers it will depend on Cron of Drupal.  You can change this setting in configuration menu.  By default Cron runs every 3 hours and will send your newsletter after that time... you can run it manually